# Unable to use transition to move text on hover

Tags: css

I am trying to use transition to move a set of text upwords when mouse is hovered on it.

```css
.mod-title {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transition: margin-top 2s ease;
}

#business:hover .mod-title {
  margin-top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="business">

  <h2 class="mod-title">Hi</h2>

</div>
```

So this is what I tried and this is the logic behind it:

I have a title that I want to be at margin-top 50% initially, but when someone howevers over the business div box, I want it to transition to 25% margin top.

So I have that in my CSS too, but nothing happens when I do that. Where am I going wrong? I do not understand, the code feels correct. Please guide me.

Comment: Seems to work fine. Look at the scroll bar when you hover the id.

Comment: As Gerard said it works fine, look at the snippet in full screen mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine.

On hover your title goes up as per CSS.

If you are considering that title should stop on top until you move cursor to another point then here is the code  http://jsfiddle.net/xd2pzkgo